# decltype( constexpr variable)

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, decltype, static-assert

Why decltype of constexpr variable is failed ?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr uint16_t foo(){ return 0;}

constexpr auto cv = foo();
          auto v  = foo();

static_assert( std::is_same< uint16_t, decltype(cv)>::value, "!"); // failed

static_assert( std::is_same< uint16_t, decltype(v) >::value, "!"); // success
```

Comment: `constexpr` variables have the `const` specifier implicitly. Try with `const unint_16_t`.

Comment: Please people, when downvote, put a comment here explaining why. A downvote without any desription about whats wrong with the question doesn't help OP at all. You should read SO unanswered questions to help people, not to enance personal ego.

Comment: @Manu343726: please take this to Meta if you wish. I have been told by moderators, such posts as this is noise in here, and should not be allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`decltype(entity)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) specifies the declared type of the `entity` specified by this expression.

Due to the [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), (*A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration implies `const`*), your `cv` variable is of type `const uint16_t`.

You know that `const uint16_t` is different from `uint16_t` then your line:

```
static_assert( std::is_same< uint16_t, decltype(cv)>::value, "!");
```

fail as this is expected.

---

The line

```
constexpr uint16_t foo(){ return 0;}
```

specifies that the function `foo` can be evaluated at compile time but the function still returns a `uint16_t`. That why on the line

```
auto v  = foo();
```

`v` is of type `uint16_t` then the line

```
static_assert( std::is_same< uint16_t, decltype(v) >::value, "!");
```

works as expected too.

Answer (score 2):

`decltype(name)` gives the type of the entity to which `name` refers.  (Note this is different behaviour from `decltype((name))` or `decltype(other-expr)`)

The variable `cv` has type `const uint16_t` (due to the `constexpr` - `constexpr` implicitly declared a variable `const`),  which is a different type from non-const `uint16_t`.  Therefore the `static_assert` fails.